# Randomly appearing and disappearing objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make an object in Unity3d that reappears and disappears randomly using the`SetActive(True/False)` command. I don't want it to move anywhere and I'm using Unity3d C# (for those who need to know) I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your prefer a safer and faster approach w/out using strings to look up method names (which is usually a bad idea), you can use a coroutine:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ToggleVisibility : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject GameObjectToHide;
    public float MinTime = 2.0f;
    public float MaxTime = 5.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ToggleVisibilityCo(GameObjectToHide));
    }

    IEnumerator ToggleVisibilityCo(GameObject someObj)
    {
        if (someObj == null) yield break;

        while(true)
        {
            someObj.SetActive(!someObj.active);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MinTime, MaxTime));
        }

    }
```

}

However you must take into account that -whatever approach you follow- if you set an object inactive, all MonoBehaviours that it contains will stop working, so you need to put this script in a GameObject that is active, and set in the inspector the `GameObjectToHide` which will be the one that will be actually activated/deactivated. See the image on how to wire the elements in the inspector

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Invoke` to call appearAndDisappear on a time and use `Random.Range` to make it a random time then on your appearAndDisappear to make it more random you can add a `Random.Range` and if its value is greater than half make it appear if not let it stay disappear then call Invoke again to make it go forever you should play with values to reach what you need

```
void Invoker() {
        Invoke("appearDisappear", Random.Range(2.0F, 5.0F));
    }

void appearDisappear(){

  float x = Random.Range(0.0F, 6.0F);
  if(x>3){
      someObj.SetActive(True);
   }
     else
         someObj.SetActive(false) ; 

 Invoker();

}
```

Comment: I get 2 error messages saying:
1:Argument '#1' cannot convert 'double' expression to type 'float'
2:The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Random.Range(float,float)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Thanks! It now works! But I think that Ricardo Amores's approach is better.